# Is it halal to marry the daughter of my divorced wife if the child is from her ex-husband?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Can a man marry his wife's daughter from her ex-husband after divorcing the wife? Does the wife's daughter from ex-husband become halal to him after he divorces his wife?

Answer (score 8):

If marriage was consummated then step-daughter became Mahram forever, even after divorce or death.

> your step-daughters under your guardianship [born] of your wives unto
>   whom you have gone in. But if you have not gone in unto them, there is
>   no sin upon you. ([Surat An-Nisa 23](https://legacy.quran.com/4/23))

Answer (score 3):

Wife's Daughter is a Mahram to the husband even if she is not raised by her. He has married her mother so he is Mahram to her and Mahram cant get married.

Reference of Quran :-

> “Forbidden to you (for marriage) are: your mothers, your daughters,
>   your sisters, your father’s sisters, your mother’s sisters, your
>   brother’s daughters, your sister’s daughters, your foster mothers who 
>   gave you suck, your foster milk suckling sisters, your wives’
>   mothers, your stepdaughters under your guardianship, born of your
>   wives to whom you have gone in — but there is no sin on you if you
>   have not gone in them (to marry their daughters), — the wives of your 
>   sons who (spring) from your own loins, and two sisters in wedlock at
>   the same time, except for what has already passed; verily, Allaah is
>   Oft-Forgiving, Most Merciful”
>
> [Surah Al-Nisa’ 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23)

Reference :- Al-Fataawa al-Jaami’ah li’l-Mar’ah al-Muslimah, 2/600

Comment: @UmHforget to add the reference

Answer (score 2):

No not at all. .. Once a man marry a woman his all daughters even belongs to other her previous husband become haram and this status remain same whether she died or divorced